# retrieving select information from nsarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array containing the following dictionaries:

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <string>15/Feb/14</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Victor</string>
    <key>sale</key>
    <string>3</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <string>21/Feb/14</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Sonny</string>
    <key>sale</key>
    <string>12</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <string>3/Feb/14</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Mike</string>
    <key>sale</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <string>02/Jan/14</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Victor</string>
    <key>sale</key>
    <string>6</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <string>04/Jan/14</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Sonny</string>
    <key>sale</key>
    <string>3</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <string>02/Jan/14</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Mike</string>
    <key>sale</key>
    <string>8</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <string>02/Dec/13</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Victor</string>
    <key>sale</key>
    <string>2</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <string>02/Dec/13</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Sonny</string>
    <key>sale</key>
    <string>8</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <string>12/Dec/13</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Mike</string>
    <key>sale</key>
    <string>0</string>
</dict>
</array>
```

I could easily retrieve the total for all dictionaries by using:

```
- (double)totalSales {
    double total = 0.0;

    for (NSDictionary *totalDictionary in salesArray) {
        total += [[totalDictionary objectForKey:@"sale"] doubleValue];    
    }

    return total;
}
```

but where I am having a problem is how to get the following:

1. the per month (only) sales total (for all persons)
2. the total sales for each person (regardless of the date).

Comment: Have you tried filtering / iterating and splitting the data up into different lists (pre month and per person). Then summing. Look at using https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html once you have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different approach. Assuming that the data you've presented is in an array called `data`:

Get the total sales by name regardless of date:

```
// Get a unique set of names
NSSet *names = [NSSet setWithArray:[data valueForKeyPath:@"name"]];

// Run through the names and get the total for each one
for (NSString *currentName in names) {
    // Get all data for the current name
    NSArray *currentNameData = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", currentName]];
    // Add up sales for that name
    NSNumber *currentNameTotal = [currentNameData valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.sale"];
    NSLog(@"%@ total: %@", currentName, currentNameTotal);
}
```

This prints:

```
2014-02-26 18:21:40.165 Untitled 5[5825:507] Victor total: 11
2014-02-26 18:21:40.166 Untitled 5[5825:507] Mike total: 9
2014-02-26 18:21:40.167 Untitled 5[5825:507] Sonny total: 23
```

Getting totals by month is a little harder since the `date` string has more than just the month name.

```
// Get a unique set of month names (loop because date contains more than the month name)
NSSet *dateStrings = [NSSet setWithArray:[data valueForKeyPath:@"date"]];
NSMutableSet *monthNames = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSString *dateString in dateStrings) {
    NSArray *dateStringComponents = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    [monthNames addObject:dateStringComponents[1]];
}
```

Using your data, `monthNames` now contains `Dec`, `Jan`, and `Feb`. Then find totals by month using a similar approach to the one above for totals by name:

```
for (NSString *monthName in monthNames) {
    // Get all data for dates containing monthName
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date CONTAINS %@", monthName];
    NSArray *currentMonthData = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    // Add up sales for that month
    NSNumber *monthTotal = [currentMonthData valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.sale"];
    NSLog(@"Total for %@: %@", monthName, monthTotal);
}
```

This prints:

```
2014-02-26 18:21:40.169 Untitled 5[5825:507] Total for Dec: 10
2014-02-26 18:21:40.175 Untitled 5[5825:507] Total for Feb: 16
2014-02-26 18:21:40.177 Untitled 5[5825:507] Total for Jan: 17
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to what you are already doing, but limit to the situations you are concerned about. For example to limit it to a single person you would do the following

```
- (double)totalSalesForPerson:(NSString *)person {
    double total = 0.0;

    for (NSDictionary *totalDictionary in salesArray) {
            if ([[totalDictionary objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString person])
                total += [[totalDictionary objectForKey:@"sale"] doubleValue];    
    }

    return total;
}
```

Try doing the same with the date. We can help you out if you run into problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

To get total sales by month, this is how I would do it. I didn't test my code, but it should be close to what you're trying to achieve.

```
- (double)totalSalesForMonth:(int)month {
    double total = 0.0;

    for (NSDictionary *totalDictionary in salesArray) {
        NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        timeFormat.dateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dd/MMM/yy"];
        NSDate *date = [timeFormat dateFromString:[totalDictionary objectForKey:@"date"]];

        [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"M"];

        if (month == [[timeFormat stringFromDate:date] intValue])
            total += [[totalDictionary objectForKey:@"sale"] doubleValue];
    }

    return total;
}
```

I've also modified @ansible's answer a little bit to convert all names to lowercase strings

```
- (double)totalSalesForPerson:(NSString *)person {
    double total = 0.0;

    for (NSDictionary *totalDictionary in salesArray) {
        if ([[[totalDictionary objectForKey:@"name"] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:[person lowercaseString]])
            total += [[totalDictionary objectForKey:@"sale"] doubleValue];
    }

    return total;
}
```